# run separate background process on java web server

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Basically I want to use a jsp web page, so in Java, to run(manager) different background process (could be anything that runs) on a linux server.

They need to be run as different user than the web itself.

I wonder what options do I have?

---

I just found out that

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("linux command");
```

may work.

But I don't know whether the (child?) process just started will be completely detached from the java servlet process? And is it possible to run it under different account?

Comment: What JEE version? In JEE 6 it's quite easy to create asynchronous services, with EJB JEE 5 you could try and use a message driven bean.

Comment: Thx Thomas. What I don't understand is how to start a complete detached native process under different account from a java world?

Comment: You probably want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html. I don't think you can do much from a JSP page, you would at least need a servlet, but even then there would be security restrictions.

Comment: Oh great! We are getting there. Will the new/child? process stop when I shut the servlet/webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Runtime` in a supposedly lifelong running Java EE web application is a bad idea.

First and foremost, a new process created by `Runtime` will by design allocate as many new heap memory as the currently running Java environment. This may not necessarily harm inside a simple Java application which uses by default 64MB or something, but in a Java EE web application which ususually allocates memory in terms of gigabytes, this is going to be a complete memory waste.

Second, you just don't want so spawn *unmanaged* processes/threads inside a Java EE web application. What if the process/thread stalls and/or runs forever which can cause unability to shutdown/restart the Java EE web application when necessary (you'd need to kill it altogether first)? What if the process crashes and takes down your whole Java EE runtime along it?

Last, you cannot change the user running the process. It will always be the same user who has executed the currently running Java runtime.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Don't use Java for this at all. For example, just do the job using platform provided background job manager, such as Cron in Unix based platforms and Task Scheduler in Windows based platforms.
2. Do it in 100% Java. Perform the same goal using pure Java, without the need to spawn a process. You can if necessary manage background jobs using `ExecutorService` API or a 3rd party library like Quartz. Note that even those jobs have still to run 100% pure Java code.